# indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: returns value outside of array count

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, indexing, nsmutablearray

I'm currently working on an app that populates a `UITableView` with items from a `MPMediaItemCollection`. I'm trying to add a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` to the row that matches the title of the currently playing track.

I've done so by creating a mutable array of the track titles, which are also set for my cell's `textLabel.text` property. (for comparison purposes)

**Note:** This is all done in `- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath`

```
MPMediaItem *mediaItem = (MPMediaItem *)[collectionMutableCopy objectAtIndex: row];

if (mediaItem) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
}



[mutArray insertObject:cell.textLabel.text atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

To the best of my knowledge this all works fine except for the below. At this point, I am trying to get the index of the currently playing tracks title and add the `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` to that row.

```
if (indexPath.row == [mutArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:[mainViewController.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Getting to my question, I added all of the above (mostly irrelevant) code because I'm stumped on where I went wrong. When I log `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` it spits out "2147483647" every time, even though there are never more than 5 objects in the array. But why?

If anyone has any tips or pointers to help me fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2147483647 just mean the object is not found.

From [the documentation of `-[NSArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1410847-indexofobjectidentical):

> #### Return Value
>
> The lowest index whose corresponding array value is identical to *anObject*. If none of the objects in the array is identical to *anObject*, returns `NSNotFound`.

and [`NSNotFound`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/foundation_constants/nsnotfound) is defined as:

```
enum {
   NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax
};
```

and 2147483647 = 0x7fffffff is the maximum integer on 32-bit iOS.

---

Please note that even if two NSString have the same content, they may not be the identical object. Two objects are identical if they share the same location, e.g.

```
NSString* a = @"foo";
NSString* b = a;
NSString* c = [a copy];

assert([a isEqual:b]);   // a and b are equal.
assert([a isEqual:c]);   // a and c are equal.
assert(a == b);          // a and b are identical.
assert(a != c);          // a and c are *not* identical.
```

I believe you just want equality test instead of identity test, i.e.

```
if (indexPath.row == [mutArray indexOfObject:[....]]) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs for [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

> **Return Value**
>   The lowest index whose corresponding array value is identical to anObject. If none of the objects in the array is identical to anObject, returns NSNotFound.

So you should probably do a check

```
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:otherObject];

if (NSNotFound == index) {
    // ... handle not being in array
} else {
    // ... do your normal stuff
}
```